# Mongodb Map Reduce By Date is One Month Off

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, date, mapreduce, mongoid

I am using mongoid in Rails and have a map reduce to output posts by date.  Locally, it works as expected however when I deploy it using Heroku/MongoLab, one of the date counts is one month behind where it should be.

map:

```
function() {
    emit(new Date(this._revisions.publish_date.getFullYear(), this._revisions.publish_date.getMonth(), 1), {count: 1});
}
```

reduce:

```
function(key, values) {
    var result = {count: 0}
    values.forEach(function(value) {
        result.count += value.count;
    });
    return result;
}
```

local results have 1 for january and 2 for july which is correct
remote results have 1 for january and 2 for june

I know about 0 index months in JavaScript, but I don't think that is the issue since it is working fine locally.  It might be a timezone issue, but not sure why that would cause it to be off by a month.

### Update

I changed the date on the record-in-question to be July 2nd instead of July 1st and it performed as expected.  Not sure why July 1st is getting emitted as June while July 2nd is emitted as July.  Seems to be an issue with all dates on the 1st of a month get emitted as the previous month and why this would only happen on a remote server and not a local one.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense.  In JavaScript January is 0, February is 1, and so on.  But as for why it's different on the two servers, that's very likely a timezone issue as you're using the local time APIs.

Comment: You could try `new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, 1))` to create a UTC date.

Comment: The fundamental problem is that a July 1 date in one time zone can be June 30th in another time zone.  You need to be using the UTC methods of `Date` instead of the local ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that you're using the local time methods of `Date` in your manipulations.  A July 1 date in one time zone can be June 30 in another time zone.

The solution is to use the UTC methods of `Date` instead of the local ones so that your date handling isn't affected by the time zone of the host server.